# Rails 4 update book_reviews issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have looked around and couldn't find a post that would resolve this particular issue.

on my browser i go to the index (book_path) page to see all the books that have been posted. The title is and a link to the show page, with details for that book.

books/index.html.erb

```
<% @books.each do |book| %><hr>
  Title: <%= link_to "#{book.title}", book_path(book)  %></a><br>
  Description: <%= book.description %><br>
  URL: <%= book.url %><br>
  Role: <%= book.user.role %><br>
  <%= link_to "Edit Book", edit_book_path(book) %>
  <%= link_to 'Delete Book', book, method: :delete,
  data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %> <hr>
<% end %>
```

books/show.html.erb - as you can see i have a an edit link_to for the details after one is added from the form.

```
<!-- show each book's detail -->
  <div>
    Title: <%= @book.title %><br>
    Description: <%= @book.description %><br>
    URL: <%= @book.url %><br>
    <%= link_to "Edit Book", edit_book_path(@book) %>
  </div><hr>


  <!-- show each review -->
  <div>
    <% @book.reviews.each do |review| %>
      <%= link_to "Edit", edit_book_review_path(@book, review) %>
      Review: <%= review.description %><hr>
    <% end %>
  </div>


  <%= render "reviews/reviewform" %>
```

reviews/edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :review, :url => { :action => 'update', @review.id => :review_id }, method: :patch do |f| %>
<p>
  <%= f.label :description %><br>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
</p>

<p>
  <%= f.submit "Update Review"%>
</p>
<% end %>
```

this is the url i get when i click on the book in my index page (expected)

```
http://localhost:3000/books/6
```

this is the url i get after clicking to edit a review (expected)

```
http://localhost:3000/books/6/reviews/13/edit
```

Though when I hit "Update Review" it gives an error (unexpected)

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in BooksController#show

Couldn't find Book with 'id'=13

def show
  @book = Book.find(params[:id])
end
```

its referring me back to my books controller

reviews_controller.rb

```
def edit
  @book = Book.find(params[:book_id])
  @review = Review.find(params[:id])
end

def update
  @review = Review.find(params[:id])

  if @review.update_attributes(review_params)
    redirect_to book_path, :notice => "Successfully Updated"
  else
    render "edit"
  end
end
```

Understandable because I'm redirecting it to the book_path, but shouldnt it just show me the book with the id 6 and the updated review?

so i changed it to

```
 def update
  @review = Review.find(params[:id])

  if @review.update_attributes(review_params)
    redirect_to book_review_path, :notice => "Successfully Updated"
  else
    render "edit"
  end
end
```

and get

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ReviewsController#show
Couldn't find Review with 'id'=6
 def show
    @review = Review.find(params[:book_id])
 end

Request

Parameters:

{"book_id"=>"6",
 "id"=>"13"}
```

routes.rb

```
               root GET    /                                          books#index
        book_reviews GET    /books/:book_id/reviews(.:format)          reviews#index
                     POST   /books/:book_id/reviews(.:format)          reviews#create
     new_book_review GET    /books/:book_id/reviews/new(.:format)      reviews#new
    edit_book_review GET    /books/:book_id/reviews/:id/edit(.:format) reviews#edit
         book_review GET    /books/:book_id/reviews/:id(.:format)      reviews#show
                     PATCH  /books/:book_id/reviews/:id(.:format)      reviews#update
                     PUT    /books/:book_id/reviews/:id(.:format)      reviews#update
                     DELETE /books/:book_id/reviews/:id(.:format)      reviews#destroy
               books GET    /books(.:format)                           books#index
                     POST   /books(.:format)                           books#create
            new_book GET    /books/new(.:format)                       books#new
           edit_book GET    /books/:id/edit(.:format)                  books#edit
                book GET    /books/:id(.:format)                       books#show
                     PATCH  /books/:id(.:format)                       books#update
                     PUT    /books/:id(.:format)                       books#update
                     DELETE /books/:id(.:format)                       books#destroy
```

i have tried other routes but no luck.
let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your
reviews_controller.rb

`def update`

action, you have

```
redirect_to book_path, :notice => "Successfully Updated"
```

It should be

```
redirect_to book_path(params[:book_id]), :notice => "Successfully Updated"
```

I guess. Same change should be done, if you want to redirect to `book_review_path`, you should specify `id` and `book_id`

Comment: It worked.. haha.. this is exciting. Thank you @Rustam